# Python __init__ Method and Property Usage in SpecAugment Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question 1:
In the forward(self, x) method of the SpecAugment class, there's a property named self._forward that seems to behave like a function. However, it also receives an 'x' variable as if it were a function. How does this interaction work?

Question 2:
After passing the 'x' value to the self._forward property, the code selects a policy from the 'policies' dictionary based on the 'policy' parameter. Assuming I understand the answer to the first question correctly, it seems that the 'x' value provided to self._forward is then used to choose one of 'self.policy1', 'self.policy2', or 'self.policy3'. How does this selection process work, and how do these policies run without explicitly taking any values?

Below is the original code for reference:

```
class SpecAugment(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,rate,policy=3,freq_mask=2,time_mask=4):
        super(SpecAugment, self).__init__()
        self.rate = rate
        self.specaug1 = nn.Sequential(
            torchaudio.transforms.FrequencyMasking(freq_mask_param=freq_mask),
            torchaudio.transforms.TimeMasking(time_mask_param=time_mask)
            
        )
        self.specaug2 = nn.Sequential(
            torchaudio.transforms.FrequencyMasking(freq_mask_param=freq_mask),
            torchaudio.transforms.TimeMasking(time_mask_param=time_mask),
            torchaudio.transforms.FrequencyMasking(freq_mask_param=freq_mask),
            torchaudio.transforms.TimeMasking(time_mask_param=time_mask)
        )

        policies = {1:self.policy1, 2:self.policy2, 3:self.policy3}
        self._forward = policies[policy]

    def forward(self,x):
        return self._forward(x)

    #this makes specaug1
    def policy1(self,x):
        probability = torch.rand(1,1).item()
        if self.rate > probability:
            return self.specaug1(x)
        return x

    #this makes specaug2
    def policy2(self,x):
        probability = torch.rand(1,1).item()
        if self.rate > probability:
            return self.specaug2(x)
        return x

    #this makes random choice because we did torch.rand
    def policy3(self,x):
        probability = torch.rand(1,1).item()
        if probability > 0.5:
            return self.policy1(x)
        return self.policy2(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to see what's happening here.

When you create an instance of `SpecAugment`, call it `sa`, the `__init__()` assigns a few properties:

- `sa.rate` contains the `rate` value
- `sa.specaug1` and `sa.specaug2` contain whatever was returned by the calls to `nn.Sequential()`
- `sa._forward` contains a *callable*: `policy1()` or `2` or `3` depending on the `policy` value you passed in

When you call `sa.forward(x)`, the callable from `sa._forward` is called with the `x` parameter. This in turn returns `x` or the result of a call to `sa.specaug1` or `2`, depending on the values of `probabibility`, `sa.rate`, and `sa._forward`.

Note that if `sa.specaug1` (or `sa.specaug2`) isn't a callable you will get an error

Comment: this makes sense. So as far as i understood correctly. `sa._forward` is called with the x parameter, and let's say policy is 3 so `self._forward` is set to `self.policy3`. This x value goes into policy3 function. I thougnt we should do it like `self.policy3(x)` or something. I was thinking like how `self.policy3` function gets the x value from `self._forward`.


doesn't it make more sense to write it like `policies = {1:self.policy1(x), 2:self.policy2(x), 3:self.policy3(x)}`

Comment: I didn't know that x parameter will be passed into the function  without writing like `self.policy1(x)`. So `self._forward = self.policy1(x)`  and `self._forward = self.policy1` is the same ?

Comment: `policies = {1:self.policy1(x)}` would set `policies[1]` to the value returned by `self.policy1(x)`. You may want to look at `functools.partial()` for a different approach